# How to add feed ads in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, ads, adsense-api

I try to add feed ads in product thumbnails of my website

There is no error and website is running fine. But No ads has been comeup in my website. How to achieve this in feed ads in WooCommerce product thumbnail.

I have edited my woocommerce-teplate.php as

```
    if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_content' ) ) {

    /**
     * Output WooCommerce content.
     *
     * This function is only used in the optional 'woocommerce.php' template.
     * which people can add to their themes to add basic woocommerce support.
     * without hooks or modifying core templates.
     */
  function woocommerce_content() {
        $i=1;
        if ( is_singular( 'product' ) ) {

            while ( have_posts() ) :
                the_post();

                                if($i==5||$i==7||$i==10){?>
                                 #my adsense code
                                <?php }

                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
            $i++;
            endwhile;

        } else {
            ?>

            <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>

                <h1 class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' ); ?>

            <?php if ( woocommerce_product_loop() ) : ?>

                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' ); ?>

                <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                <?php if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) : ?>
                    <?php $i++;  while ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                        <?php the_post(); ?>

                        <?php  if($i==5||$i==7||$i==10){?>
                          #my adsense code
                        <?php }?>

                        <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
                    <?php $i++;?>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Please be more clearer. It's all greek to me.

Comment: When you display products in homepage, I need to display ads in between. Google gives in feed ad code to be placed between products. I have pasted that code in my template file. Still I dont see any ads on my homepage.